# How to upload socket io chatroom code on cpanel

Tags: socket.io

i have used the code as following
index.html

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
        <style>
          * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
          body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
          form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
          form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
          form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
          #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
          #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
          #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <form action="">
          <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script>
          var socket = io();
          $('form').submit(function(){
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
          });
          socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and then i have to write node index on command prompt and then i can access the chatroom using localhost:3000

but when i upload it to cpanel and open my url the chatroom is not running do i have to do something like putting a command or have to do something with Cpanel?
Thanks
Regards